# how to provide username and password while checking out the code from SVN using python script without third party module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, svn, svn-checkout

I am able to write a script to checkout the code from SVN issue using "pysvn" module but just wanted to know is there any way I can do without pysvn also ? Because pysvn is third party library which I have to install separately on linux and windows both which I don't want. Please help me get alternate way in which I don't have to install any third party module                                 code -

```
import pysvn,os,shutil


def getLogin(realm, username, may_save):
    svn_user = '<my-username>'
    svn_pass = '<my-password>'
    return True, svn_user, svn_pass, False

def ssl_server_trust_prompt( trust_dict ):
    return (True    # server is trusted
           ,trust_dict["failures"]
           ,True)   # save the answer so that the callback is not called again

def checkOut(svn_url,dest_dir):
    if os.path.isdir(dest_dir):
        shutil.rmtree(dest_dir)
        os.mkdir(dest_dir)
        client = pysvn.Client()
    client.callback_ssl_server_trust_prompt = ssl_server_trust_prompt
        client.callback_get_login = getLogin
        client.checkout(svn_url,dest_dir)
    else:
        os.mkdir(dest_dir)
        client = pysvn.Client()
    client.callback_ssl_server_trust_prompt = ssl_server_trust_prompt
        client.callback_get_login = getLogin
        client.checkout(svn_url,dest_dir)


print "Checking out the code hang on...\n"
checkOut('<svn-repo>','ABC')
print "checked out the code \n"

print "Checking out the code hang on...\n"
checkOut('<svn-repo>','XYZ')
print "checked out the code\n"

print "Checking out the code hang on...\n"
checkOut('<svn-repo>','MNP')
print "checked out the code \n”
```

Comment: share snippets that you have tried.

Comment: one I tried like this import os
os.system('svn co https://svn-path') . Here it pops up with password window always. I am running this on ubuntu

Comment: other I tried with subprocess the same way. please help

Answer (score 1):

You can pass username and password as arguments:

```
$ svn update --username 'user2' --password 'password'
```

Comment: I have provided code with enough information in the description part. I request you guys to please re-open and help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can make Executable of ur script which will include the pysvn into binary file, thus wouldn't need to import or pip install any library, n ur code will run on python-less machines too